# Function which gets two equal size integer arrays and number of elements as parameters and displays sum of parallel elements of both arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

The code I wrote is given below, it does not let the user input all required elements to the arrays that the user selected,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int x, int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
    int i;
    int sum[x];

    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        sum[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];
    }
    printf("The total of the two arrays is  ");
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
    printf("%d", sum[i]);
}
int main()
{
    int i, x;
    printf("Enter the size of the arrays \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    int arr1[x], arr2[x];
    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d for array 1  ", i++);
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
      for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d for array 2  ", i++);
        scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);
    }
    add(x, arr1, arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

But when  `printf("Enter number %d for array 1  ", i++);` and  `printf("Enter number %d for array 2  ", i++);` changed to `printf("Enter number %d for array 1  ", i+1);` and  `printf("Enter number %d for array 2  ", i+1);` I could over come the problem, please state the reason for it.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d for array 1  ", i++); ... }` is incrementing `i` twice per loop.  Surely it should be once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you first need to read up on [Increment and decrement operator in C](https://www.programiz.com/article/increment-decrement-operator-difference-prefix-postfix).

Simply put, `i++` is not the same as `i+1`.

`i+1` will add 1 to `i`, but it will not change `i` itself.

```
i = 1;
printf("%d", i+1);
printf("%d", i);
```

The output will be `2` and `1`.

Now `i++` changes `i`. It translates to `i=i+1`.

```
i = 1;
printf("%d", i++);
printf("%d", i);
```

The output will be `2` and `2`. Notice that `i` has changed.

Now coming to your problem.

```
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    printf("Enter number %d for array 1  ", i++);
    scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
}
```

Here, the `for` loop increments `i` (`i++`) and also the `printf` statement increments `i` (`i++`).

Let's take a numerical example.

```
int x=4;
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", i++);
}
```

The output will be

```
0 2
```

Notice how numbers are skipped because of the double increment.

But if your loop was :

```
int x=4;
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", i+1);
}
```

The output would be

```
1 2 3 4
```